# reading a .txt save file in CPP and save the value to local variable

Tags: c++, save

i'm new in C++ (and file input output), I learned how to use fprint to print something from a .txt in a formatted style, but how do I search for a certain value and save that value in a local variable? below is the code for save:

```
 void savestate(state a){ //state is a struct with data I need such as position etc
    FILE * save;
    int data[]= { a.level, a.goalX, a.goalX, a.monX, a.monY }; 
    save = fopen("game.txt", "wb"); // << might have to use suggestion C 
    fwrite(data, sizeof(int), sizeof(data), save); // is this actually the correct way to do it?
    fclose(save);
 }
```

as for load, I'm stuck with this:

```
void loadstate(){
    FILE* save;
    save = fopen("game.txt", "rb");
    if(save== NULL) perror("no savegame data");
    else{ 
         // don't even know what function I should use
    }
```

and by the way, after I activate the save function, the game.txt is not in a quite readable format. I can open in in my notepad, but it shows something like ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌøäÁ_ÌÌÌÌúƒ which makes no sense. any idea? :D

Comment: Don't write `.txt` files as binary.  You are writing bits, not ASCII in the above code.  The arguments of `fwrite` are `buffer, size, count, stream` -- `sizeof(data)` is not the count of the number of elements in `data`.

Comment: @Yakk sorry, I don't really understand, I followed an example in cplusplus tutorial. how do I know if I write .txt as binary and in ASCII? I'll try changing the sizeof to just 5 then

Comment: In c++ use the classes and functions of the standard [I/O library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)! If you insist to work with `FILE*` use the `fprintf()` function to write text to the file.

Comment: It looks like you are expecting `fwrite` to convert the data to a text representation. That is not what `fwrite` does, it just writes the raw data out to the file with no conversion.

Comment: ^ and ^^ thanks for the information. I'll try using fprintf. sorry I'm having a bit of difficulty reading the library :/ how do I open the file and store the values?

Comment: @Rei To open the file use the `open()` function of `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream` classes. To store values use the stream output operator `<<`, to read values use the stream input operator `>>`.

Comment: why you using c filing? why not c++ fstream filing?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I followed your advice and use fprintf, and it saved the file in readable txt format, yay :D. I don't understand what you mean to read with >> though, which function of ofstream do I use to read it?

Comment: @Rei It's a non member overloaded operator function [`operator<<()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), see the documentation and examples for usage in the link. For reading you use the pendant for `std::istream`, [`operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ finally get it right. thank you. I don't know why but I had a more difficult time learning C++ than java. maybe the syntax or documentation, there's so many of them @.@

Comment: @Rei Keep with that reference I've mentioned. It's the most concise and complete around by now IMHO. Java is very different, yes. There's no operator overloading, templates and this stuff of fancy things. I think learning it the other way round is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use text file for this purpose, not a binary file. The saveData function
will create the data.txt file and then the function loadData reads the data from the file. I you want some more explanation leave a comment below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void saveData() {
    FILE* f = fopen("data.txt", "w");
    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("cant save data");
        return;
    }
    //write some data (as integer) to file
    fprintf(f, "%d %d %d\n", 12, 45, 33);
    fprintf(f, "%d %d %d\n", 1, 2, 3);
    fprintf(f, "%d %d %d\n", 9, 8, 7);

    fclose(f);
}

void loadData() {
    int data1, data2, data3;
    FILE* f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("cant open file");
        return;
    }
    //load data from file, fscanf return the number of read data
    //so if we reach the end of file (EOF) it return 0 and we end
    while(fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &data1, &data2, &data3) == 3) {
        printf("data1 = %d data2 = %d data3 = %d\n", data1, data2, data3);
    }

    fclose(f);

}

int main() {
    saveData();
    loadData();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

example of writing to a file:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int i = 78;
string word = "AWord";
ofstream fout("AFile", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary | ios_base::trunc);
fout << i;
fout << endl;
fout << word;
fout.close();

return 0
}
```

example of reading from a file :

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int ix;
string wordx;
ifstream fin("AFile", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
fin >> ix;
while(fin.get() != '\n'){
   fin.get();
}
fin >> wordx;
fin.close();

return 0
}
```

Comment: If you read the question a bit closer, it becomes clear the OP doesn't want to have binary data in the file.